# Subsetting GPS data

Tags: r

I want to subset GPS data points (easting northings) from birds UCOL10, UCOL27, UCOL29 and UCOL30) and Im using the OR statement | (vertical line) to include all 4 birds. Is this the correct use of the OR statement as coded below:

```
main[main$subject_name=="UCOL10 | UCOL27 | UCOL29 | UCOL30",c(23,24)]
#[1] eastings  northings
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
main$subject_name=="UCOL10 | UCOL27 | UCOL29 | UCOL30"
```

is illegal. Do either

```
main$subject_name %in% c("UCOL10", "UCOL27", "UCOL29", "UCOL30")
```

or

```
main$subject_name == "UCOL10" | main$subject_name == "UCOL27" | 
     main$subject_name == "UCOL29" | main$subject_name == "UCOL30"
```

The first option uses `%in%`, see `?"%in%"` for more info. It is much neater than using logical or `|` as in the second option.